# Sprockets::FileNotFound couldn't find file 'hamlcoffee' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, haml, sprockets

I added gem `haml_coffee_assets` like shown here: https://github.com/emilioforrer/haml_coffee_assets.
Then try to test it:

```
:javascript   $(document).ready( function() {
    $('.questions').append(JST['test']({ test: "TTTEEESSSTT"));
    });
```

Has anybody faced with similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/emilioforrer/haml_coffee_assets/issues/152#issuecomment-217953205

> I just found this bug in a new project, where JST is undefined. I
>   seems to be an incompatibility with sprockets-rails v3+.
>
> As a work around you, can downgrade sprockets-rails to gem
>   "sprockets-rails", "2.3.3" until this bug gets fixed